# Close localhost tab automatically msal library

Tags: python, azure, azure-ad-msal

I'm using `msal` library for `python` and i have completed all registration on Microsoft Azure including set http://localhost as a redirection url in the active directory to be able to use the acquire_token_interactive function to fetch the token

```
import logging

from pprint import pprint

import msal
import requests

config = {
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations",
    "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "username": "XXXXX@XXXX.com",
    "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "scope": ["User.ReadBasic.All"],
    "endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
}


app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    config["client_id"], authority=config["authority"],
    # allow_broker=True,  # If opted in, you will be guided to meet the prerequisites, when applicable
    # See also: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-wam#wam-value-proposition
    # token_cache=...  # Default cache is in memory only.
    # You can learn how to use SerializableTokenCache from
    # https://msal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#msal.SerializableTokenCache
)
result = None

accounts = app.get_accounts(username=config.get("username"))
if accounts:
    logging.info("Account(s) exists in cache, probably with token too. Let's try.")
    print("Account(s) already signed in:")
    for a in accounts:
        print(a["username"])
    chosen = accounts[0]  # Assuming the end user chose this one to proceed
    print("Proceed with account: %s" % chosen["username"])
    # Now let's try to find a token in cache for this account
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(config["scope"], account=chosen)

if not result:
    logging.info("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
    print("A local browser window will be open for you to sign in. CTRL+C to cancel.")
    result = app.acquire_token_interactive(

        port=5001,

        # Only works if your app is registered with redirect_uri as http://localhost
        scopes=config["scope"],

        # parent_window_handle=...,  # If broker is enabled, you will be guided to provide a window handle
        login_hint=config.get("username"),  # Optional.
        # If you know the username ahead of time, this parameter can pre-fill
        # the username (or email address) field of the sign-in page for the user,
        # Often, apps use this parameter during reauthentication,
        # after already extracting the username from an earlier sign-in
        # by using the preferred_username claim from returned id_token_claims.
        on_before_launching_ui=lambda ui="browser", **kwargs: print(
            "A {} will be launched you can close the the tab".format(ui))
        # prompt=msal.Prompt.SELECT_ACCOUNT,  # Or simply "select_account". Optional. It forces to show account selector page
        # prompt=msal.Prompt.CREATE,  # Or simply "create". Optional. It brings user to a self-service sign-up flow.
        # Prerequisite: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/self-service-sign-up-user-flow
    )


if "access_token" in result:
    # print(result["access_token"])
    pprint(result)
    # Calling graph using the access token
    graph_response = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        config["endpoint"],
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']}, )
    # print("Graph API call result: %s ..." % graph_response.text)
    # pprint(graph_response.json())
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))  # You may need this when reporting a bug
```

The content of redirection after successful authentication:
Authentication completed. You can close this window now.
with link: localhost:XXX/?code=0.ATAXXXXXX&session_state=8beXXXXXX

how I can close the localhost tab automatically
Is there a way to automate this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigation, I have found the
`success_template` param

We need to add it to the `acquire_token_interactive()` function

And I have injected the JS code into it after 3 seconds the window will be closed

`success_template`=`"""<html><body><script>setTimeout(function(){window.close()}, 3000);</script></body></html> """`